# Xcode .bundle and .dylib

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, cydia

Is there a way to combine .bundle and .dylib into one file. I have written a tweak and a preference bundle for it. How do I have them to be installed as one?

Answer (score 1):

you have to pack all the tweak files in a **[DEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format))** package

for example create a directory named **Tweak**
and inside it create another directory named **DEBIAN** in debian directory create a text file called control

***inside control***

```
Package: com.example.tweak
Name: Tweak
Version: 1.0
Architecture: iphoneos-arm
Author: Sull <email@email.com>
Depiction: http://yourdepiction.com/example
Description: Example description here.
Homepage: http://example.com
Maintainer: Sull <email@email.com>
Section: Tweaks
```

> *When done editing your control file, go to the end of the last line and press the enter/return key, now save the file. You always have to go to the last line and press enter or you'll run into errors when building.

as you said you have a Preferences bundle and a Dylib so the Tweak directory should look like this

```
/Tweak
----/DEBIAN
--------/control
----/Library
--------/MobileSubsttrate
------------/DynamicLibraries
----------------/tweak.dylib
----------------/tweak.plist
--------/PreferenceLoader
------------/Preferences
----------------/tweakPref.plist
--------/PreferenceBundles
------------/tweakPref.bundle
```

now run the command **dpkg -b /Tweak** in terminal

> Assuming the **Tweak** folder is in root
>
> You can ignore these warnings they are completely normal.
>   warning, `Tweak/DEBIAN/control' contains user-defined field`Name'
>   warning, `Tweak/DEBIAN/control' contains user-defined field`Author'
>   warning, `Tweak/DEBIAN/control' contains user-defined field`Sponsor'
>   dpkg-deb: ignoring 3 warnings about the control file(s)

there will be a file named **Tweak.deb** you can install it to the iPhone via terminal or apps like iFile